# How can I make iPhone hotspot login UIWebView open a link in Safari?

Tags: iphone

We have a wifi hotspot that displays a terms of service page before people are allowed to start using it.

After acceptance, a new page with a few links is displayed. I'd like to have those links open in Safari instead of in UIWebView.

I know there's a way to program UIWebView to open links in Safari, but that's not an option as this is the default UIWebView for logging into wifi hotspots and not a custom app.

Is there another way to have the links open in Safari and not in UIWebView? I've tried javascript and I've tried setting the target to _blank.

EDIT: After reading some responses, it seems like the only way to do this is to set the UIWebView delegate. I don't think this is an option because I'm not the one launching the UIWebView.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to do this is to set up a UIWebView delegate and supply something like the following:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked &&
        [request.URL isFileURL] == false)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

The code above will cause Safari to open a link clicked on by the user. I know you said you had little control over this UIWebView -- perhaps you have more than you think by setting the delegate?

Comment: `BOOL` values are `YES` and `NO`, not `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 1):

When the iPhone connects to the network (at least with version 3.0), it checks to see if it's being redirected to a login page. If it is, it does what you're saying with authentication and such inside of a UIWebView. Have you checked to see what it's reporting as the browser in use? If it isn't Mobile Safari, then you could do something server-side the first time someone connects using Mobile Safari.

If it does report as Mobile Safari when it's checking redirection, then another alternative is to figure out what site it tries to go to - maybe apple.com? Then, on the server side, the first time a *different* URL is loaded, redirect to your links. This will only work when the user opens Mobile Safari, however.

Other than that, I think what you're asking to do is outside of the scope of the current iPhone OS. I'd recommend filing a ‘feature request’ with Apple at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`openURL`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL:) method of UIApplication:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://example.com"];    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
[url release];
```

An Apple example of this is available as part of the [LaunchMe](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/samplecode/LaunchMe/listing2.html) sample.